# How can Chrome Extension identify browser authentication with a website -- manifest 3?

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension

Locally on my mac book, my chrome extension is trying to identify whether or not my chrome browser is signed into a specific website. I am referencing [these docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/). However, the cookie data I am getting back for this specific website is the same regardless of whether or not my browser has authenticated with the site. This is what the cookie looks like printed to console:

```
{
    "domain": "some-random-string.ngrok.io",
    "hostOnly": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "_the_app_session",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "unspecified",
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "random sttring"
}
```

This is the code I am running:

```
// Attempt
chrome.cookies.getAll(
    {"url": "https://some-random-string.ngrok.io", "name": "_the_app_session"},
    function(cookies) {
      console.log('cookies', cookies)
    }
  )

// Attempt
chrome.cookies.get({"url": "https://some-random-string.ngrok.io", "name": "_the_app_session"}, function(cookie) {
   console.log('cookie', cookie)
 });
```

How can my chrome extension identify whether or not my browser is signed into a specific website?

This is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "16": "cooking-icon.png",
    "128": "cooking-icon.png"
  },
  "name": "Some app",
  "description": "A Chrome extension app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_title": "App",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My work around for this was to create an endpoint in my app which would check whether or not the browser was signed in. Make a GET request to this endpoint:

```
const authenticated = await fetch('http://random-string.ngrok.io/authenticated', {
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include'
    });
```

Based on the response my chrome extension could tell whether or not my browser has signed into the site.

Comment: How can your extension access your server without sending the cookie in its own requests? What do you do with that information in your extension?

Comment: All the above endpoint does is check whether or not my browser is signed in to my web app. If the user is signed in, the endpoint responds back with the user data of the signed-in user. Otherwise, the server responds with 401, and the extension lets the user know that they need to sign into my web app.

The authentication cookie which is signed on my server and added to the header is cached in the browser. All the above endpoint does is service calls from my browser extension to check whether or not the client, the browser, is indeed authenticated with my web app.

Comment: I was not aware that the extension can send the same cookies as the website but I figured out that I can do that by setting the correct host permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Could you not use the cookie api to check if the Auth cookie is present?

Comment: hmm interesting this is my host permissions in the manifest:
"host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
I didn't realize the above had the side effects which you are specifying

Comment: I guess I could use that API but for me it was simpler for my web app server to be the source of truth in this case